# Python version and site-packages mismatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyenv

A few months ago I installed `pyenv` to experiment with some newer versions of python. Now, whenever I try to run scripts that formerly worked, I see a `Module Not Found Exception` despite any imported modules existing.

I suspect the problem is that the `site-packages` directory referenced by `pip3` is `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` and running `python3 --version` on my mac output `Python 3.7.9`.

I am able to install modules and they are recognized by my script if I install them using the `python3 -m pip install <package>`, but I miss the functionality of using pip3, especially since I have some scripts that specifically use `pip3`.

I have removed the `pyenv` from `.zprofile`, removed the `pyenv` directory, and uninstalled via brew.  Can anyone suggest another solution?